# MS network load balancing with multiple host header

Tags: iis, load-balancing

Currently, I have a webserver running multiple websites. All these websites each have a host name of xxx.domain.com. I am told to implement MS load balancing on the server. After I have implemented NLB to cluster to 2 server, how am I supposed to bind the websites using host name ? Below is my NLB configurations:

webserver01 IP : 10.10.0.1

webserver02 IP : 10.10.0.2

ClusterIP IP : 10.10.0.3

website 1 is to have a hostname of web1.domain.com

website 2 is to have a hostname of web2.domain.com

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 4):

Its pretty simple just replace the IP of

website 1 hostname of web1.domain.com with Cluster IP in DNS

website 2 hostname of web2.domain.com with Cluster IP in DNS

in your case ClusterIP IP : `10.10.0.3`

because when we create NLB the Cluster IP is directly transfer your request to the nodes

It works. I have already checked it.